# Transfer Animation from timeline to action editor

Tags: animation

All of my animations are on the main timeline.   How do I make single actions/stash them.   I can't copy and paste frames in there so what can I do.

Comment: not sure what's your problem, if you open the Dopesheet and switch it to Action Editor mode, you'll see that your object's action has already a name, so you can close, duplicate, create a new one, etc... If you click on the arrow icon (Only Includes Channels...) you'll only see what's the action for the selected object(s)

Comment: I have 1 single action.  That action is over 5,000 key frames.   How am I supposed to take parts of that one big action and maker more smaller actions out of it.

Comment: For example you can copy the part you want, create a new action, and paste, or duplicate your big action and delete the parts you don't want...

Comment: I tried to copy the frames I wanted and paste them but it wasn't pasting anything in there.   Got Facebook?  Can I show you on video chat?  Or can you meet me in blender animation chat and I'll show you on video what im doing?

Comment: I've just realized that if you want to copy paste from an action to another you need to create at least one keyframe in the new action. You can link a video in your question if you want